# MS Sql - update X number of rows based on another table's content

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have 2 tables, for this example "table1" and "table2".

table1 contains 100 entries and its structure is like this:

```
id (int), count(int), code(varchar(50))
```

table2 contains many thousands of rows and its structure is like this:

```
id (int), code(varchar(50))
```

I would need to make a select on table1, select all rows, all the data, then switch to table 2 and copy the code to X number of rows. where X is the number extracted from the table 1.

so if for example table1 contains a line "1","17","abc123" and a line "2","26","cde456" then it should update the first 17 lines of table2 with the code "abc123" and the next 26 lines with "cde456".

can this be done with a query or do I have to do it with a dedicated softare?

Edit:

It is not working properly. this is what I tested so far from the answer below:

```
WITH Grps AS(
SELECT LAG([qty],1,1) OVER (ORDER BY timecol ASC) AS CountStart,
       [qty] AS CountEnd,
       sscc,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timecol asc) AS RN
FROM QtyInfo),
CTE AS(
SELECT id,
       sscc,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id asc) AS RN
FROM CrateCodes)
UPDATE C
SET sscc = G.sscc
FROM CTE C
 JOIN Grps G ON C.RN BETWEEN G.CountStart AND G.CountEnd  where G.RN < 10;
```

what it does is: on table 2 the update begins always from row 0. so it keeps overwriting the same rows continuously.

here is some sample data:

```
USE [Line01]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Table1]    Script Date: 24.11.2020 16:58:20 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [count] [int] NULL,
    [code] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Table2]    Script Date: 24.11.2020 16:58:20 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [code] [varchar](50) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Table2_code]  DEFAULT ('XXX')
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([id], [count], [code]) VALUES (1, 2, N'ABC')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([id], [count], [code]) VALUES (2, 5, N'BCD')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([id], [count], [code]) VALUES (3, 1, N'DEF')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([id], [count], [code]) VALUES (4, 2, N'EFG')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([id], [count], [code]) VALUES (5, 5, N'HIJ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([id], [count], [code]) VALUES (6, 3, N'IJK')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([id], [count], [code]) VALUES (7, 2, N'LMN')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([id], [count], [code]) VALUES (8, 3, N'OPQ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([id], [count], [code]) VALUES (9, 4, N'RST')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([id], [count], [code]) VALUES (10, 4, N'UVW')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([id], [count], [code]) VALUES (11, 1, N'XYZ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([id], [count], [code]) VALUES (12, 2, N'TZU')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Table1] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (1, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (2, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (3, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (4, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (5, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (6, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (7, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (8, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (9, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (10, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (11, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (12, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (13, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (14, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (15, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (16, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (17, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (18, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (19, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (20, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (21, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (22, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (23, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (24, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (25, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (26, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (27, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (28, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (29, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (30, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (31, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (32, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (33, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (34, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (35, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (36, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (37, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (38, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (39, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (40, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (41, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (42, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (43, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (44, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (45, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (46, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (47, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (48, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (49, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (50, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (51, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (52, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (53, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (54, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (55, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (56, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (57, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (58, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (59, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (60, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (61, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (62, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (63, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (64, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (65, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (66, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (67, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (68, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (69, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (70, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (71, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (72, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (73, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (74, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (75, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (76, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (77, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (78, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (79, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (80, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (81, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (82, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (83, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (84, N'XXX')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([id], [code]) VALUES (85, N'XXX')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Table2] OFF
GO
```

Comment: You could achieve this quite easily with an updatable CTE. What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

Comment: I have no clue where to start, so I didnt try anything. but if you can point me in the right direction I can test

Comment: *"on table 2 the update begins always from row 0. so it keeps overwriting the same rows continuously."* What does that mean? What else would you expect when you update "rows" 1-10? Of course it'll update those rows.

Comment: in the sample above, the first entry of table1 has count=17 and second entry has count=26.. so i expect that in table2 the first 17 lines contain the code "abc123", and the next 26 lines of table 2 contain "cde456". currently in table 2 the first 17 lines contain "abc123" and then they are overwritten by "cde456" since instead of continuing with the lines from 18 onward its starting again from line 0

Comment: Sample data will help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you are after:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1 (ID int IDENTITY,
                         [Count] int,
                         Code varchar(6));
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2 (ID int IDENTITY,
                         Code varchar(6));
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Table1
VALUES(5,'abc123'),(3,'def456');
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Table2
VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL);
GO

WITH Grps AS(
    SELECT ISNULL(SUM([Count]) OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),1) AS CountStart,
           SUM([Count]) OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS CountEnd,
           Code
    FROM Table1),
CTE AS(
    SELECT ID,
           Code,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RN
    FROM Table2)
UPDATE C
SET Code = G.Code
FROM CTE C
     JOIN Grps G ON C.RN BETWEEN G.CountStart AND G.CountEnd;
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Table2;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.Table1;
DROP TABLE dbo.Table2;
```

Comment: thank you.. I am trying to understand the code... "update C", and "G.Code", how do you define what C and G is?  the query is currently running since 2 minutes..

Comment: can this be limited to only the firs 10 lines of table 1 to test it?

Comment: `C` and `G` are aliases @sharkyenergy `FROM CTE C` and `JOIN Grps G`.

Comment: *"can this be limited to only the firs 10 lines of table 1 to test it?"* Yes, just add a `WHERE` on  `RN`.

Comment: Isnt RN part of table2?? think i am misunderstanding your code here..

Comment: You can add an `RN` to `Grps` too @sharkyenergy .

Comment: Thank you, that part works now. unfortunately there is still something wrogn with the code. (i updated the question). it is updating the same rows on each run. so on table 2, it always starts from row 0...

Comment: Like I said, without sample data, and expected result, it was completed **untested** @sharkyenergy . Provide sample data and expected results, so we can test our solutions.

Comment: is tehre a online database/service where i can set up some sample data?

Comment: I have updated the answer with guessed sample data, @sharkyenergy .

Comment: I've also demonstrated how you provide sample data in the answer for you, @sharkyenergy .